# Pandas/Python: How to match rows of 2 dataframes together based on close but not equal values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to Python and Pandas and could really use some help on this one..

Background- I'm trying to extract unsynchronised dual-doppler measurements from a scanning `LiDAR` which is taking PPI scans. I have the data (from MySQL) loaded into pandas dataframes, and now need to apply some matching function where the rows are matched if the time of measurement is within some limit (time < 8s apart).

Here is an example of what is contained in the dataframes: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b0cc61b461c9e2d8f7bf

Column `dt_stop` (from `LabView`) is measured in seconds and is what I want to match based on.
 So in this example, row 0 of `df1` would have no match since there is 20 seconds between it and any row contained within `df2`.
 Row 1 of `df1` would be a match to row 0 of `df2` since there they are only 0.5 seconds apart.
 I would like all the matches to be concatenated horizontally so that I can perform my calculations along the same row.

I hope this makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my current code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6dee303f4f8260600fdd

Comment: This seems like a `join` condition that is much much better expressed in the database prior to loading into Pandas. If you have it in MySQL, just do a join based on the condition you want directly, like `select * from table1 a join table2 b on ABS(a.dt_stop - b.dt_stop) <= 8` -- or use fancy datetime functions as needed. After that, pivoting so that multiple matches become different columns will be easier in Pandas.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! I tried to do that in the beginning, but couldn't get it to work right. These are the two queries I'm using to get the data for each scanner. It's all stored on 4 separate tables. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/360e1adb94332c4e627e

Comment: Thanks Mr. F! I figured it out and posted the SQL solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took Mr. F's advice and solved it inside the Query.

Here is what I did for future reference.. hope it helps someone!

```
SELECT wk.gw_id, wk.scn_id, wk.dt_start, wk.dt_stop, wk.azim, wkdat.radSpeed, wkdat.cnr, wkdat.disp,
wst.gw_id, wst.scn_id, wst.dt_start, wst.dt_stop, wst.azim, wstdat.radSpeed, wstdat.cnr, wstdat.disp  
FROM wisscas.wind_def_koshava wk
inner join wisscas.wind_def_sterenn wst on (abs(wk.dt_stop-wst.dt_stop)<2.0 and abs(wk.dt_start-wst.dt_start)<2.0)
inner join wisscas.wind_data_koshava wkdat on (wk.gw_id = wkdat.gw_id)
inner join wisscas.wind_data_sterenn wstdat on (wst.gw_id = wstdat.gw_id)
where wk.scn_id = 177 
and wk.azim between 2 and 3 
and wkdat.dist = 6160
and wst.scn_id = 252
and wst.azim between 262 and 263 
and wstdat.dist = 2480
limit 0,5000;
```